# Как передать в качестве аргумента любой объект класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть такой код,чтобы функции PlayerAtk() и OpAtk() работали, я добавил в аргументы  **init**() обоих классов поле(если честно не уверен как это называется) target, которое принимает объект класса, но вот в чём суть, чтобы создать объект одного из этих классов, нужно создать объект другого класса перед этим. Естественно - ничего таким образом не работает, вот мой  вопрос: Можно ли каким-то образом, аргументу target при создании объекта присвоить любой объект другого класса, который будет создан в будущем и будет ли это работать?

```
    class Player:
        def __init__(self,p_hp, p_weap, target):
            self.p_health = p_hp
            self.p_weapon = p_weap
            self.target = target
            
        def PlayerAtk(self):
            self.target.op_health -= self.p_weapon.weapon_damage
            print(self.target.op_health)
    class Opp:
        def __init__(self,op_name, op_hp, op_dmg, target):
            self.op_name = op_name
            self.op_health = op_hp
            self.op_damage = op_dmg
        def OpAtk(self):
            self.target.p_hp -= self.op_dmg
            print(self.target.p_hp)
    class Weapon:
        def __init__(self,w_name, w_dmg):
            self.weapon_name = w_name
            self.weapon_damage = w_dmg
    pistol = Weapon("Pistol", 10)
    monster = Opp("Monster",10, 15, human)
    human = Player(10, pistol, monster)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всегда можете имплементировать класс так, чтобы можно было задать target потом.
Например:

```
    class Opp:
        def __init__(self,op_name, op_hp, op_dmg):
            ...

        def set_target(self, target):
            self.target = target
        ...

    monster = Opp("Monster",10, 15)
    human = Player(10, pistol, monster)
    monster.set_target(human)
```

Класс `Player` можно сделать наподобие (задание через отдельный метод), чтобы однотипно было.